Why is my MS word (mac) document adding a page break after text of certain custom style?
When planning my assignments, I scaffold my MS word document (mac) with a three-tier heading system using custom styles, which are named as follows: 'Primary Headings', 'Secondary Headings', and 'Tertiary Headings'.
As far as I am aware, the problem is only with the 'Tertiary Headings' style.
When ever I apply this style to a line of text and hit 'return' (enter) to create a new line underneath, the document seems to insert a page break right after it (all the text after the new line gets pushed onto the next page).
However, when I turn paragraph markers on, it doesn't show a page break.
Screenshot of the document:

I tried deleting the style, and creating an identical one from scratch, but the problem persisted with the new style.
Screenshot of the 'Tertiary Headings' style information:


The text on the new page has the following characteristics: Keep with Next and Keep Lines Together as paragraph formatting.
There is no page break; there is paragraph formatting.
First question, though, is why are you not using the Built-In Heading Styles?
See: Why use Word's Built-In Heading Styles? by Word MVP Shauna Kelly
Try going back to that last heading where the page broke. Place your insertion point at the end of that paragraph and press Enter. If you are again on a new page, check the paragraph formatting there. Disable "Keep with Next" formatting.
If it does not break, then you can type more here. If you need your tertiary heading on that page, check the paragraph formatting of the text that follows it. Does your normal style have the setting to keep with next or keep lines together?
